# Java Calendar class

Tags: java

I copied code from the web for calculating the number of days between two dates. it often produces incorrect results.  For example, The days between 01/15/2008 and 03/15/2010 are 790.  The code returns 789.  The days between 12/30/2013 and 02/28/2017 are 1156.  The code returns 1152.  Are the errors due to the code or Calendar class?  I am copying the code below.  This is my first post and I apologize for any protocol errors.
Thanks,
Nick

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateExperiment2 
{ 
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    // Create Calendar instances
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Set the values for the calendar fields YEAR, MONTH, and DAY_OF_MONTH.
    calendar1.set(2008, 1, 15);
    calendar2.set(2010, 3, 15);

    //Get Calendars' time value in milliseconds
    long miliSecondForDate1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
    long miliSecondForDate2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();

    // Calculate the difference in millisecond between two dates
    long diffInMilis = miliSecondForDate1 - miliSecondForDate2;

   //Convert milliseconds to days
    long diffInDays = diffInMilis / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    System.out.println(diffInDays);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. There's no need for a Swing UI or `isValidDateStr`, or the variables a-f - just hard-code the calls to `set`. As a separate matter, do you actually need to use `java.util.Calendar` at all? I'd strongly recommend using `java.time.LocalDate` for this instead.

Comment: Thanks.  This was my first post.  In the future I will use your guidelines.  However, the question remains. Does the Calendar class return incorrect results?

Comment: There's no need to wait for the next question. You should edit this one into good shape - that will make it easier to help you, as well as it being more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The results and the is good 
But when you set month on 01

```
`Calendar.Set(2000,1,15)`
```

That means you set it on 15 February 2000
Month on Calender start from 0

0 =is January 
1= February...